# Тайна рождения китов, овец и медведей

Tags: склонение

Вот говорят:
Кошка *окотилась* (родился котёнок).

Собака - *ощенилась* (родился щенок).

Лошадь *ожеребилась* (родился жеребенок).

Корова *отелилась* (родился телёнок).

Как быть с китами, овцами и медведями?

Comment: Да, на сколько я могу предположить - все таки - Овца оягнилась (детёныш овцы - ягнёнок)

Comment: Как ни странно, овцы и козы - котятся. Забейте в любой поисковик - Яндекс, Гугл - слово "окот" и удивитесь. Почему так я не знаю. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/901174

Comment: Об овце тоже можно сказать "окотилась". А с человеками как быть?

Comment: Никак. Человек родил(а) человека. Все эти "отсуществительные глаголы" принижают процесс, потому используются только с "сельскими" животными, которые используются с практическими целями - поле вспахать или мышей поймать. Там где важна практическая выгода от результата родов, и почти только она. Аналогично, как животных считали "10 голов", а крестьян - "10 душ". Хотя казалось бы какая разницы что считать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Словообразование - штука нерегулярная. То, что есть *белеть, чернеть, синеть и зеленеть*, не значит, что есть *фиолетоветь*.

Просто: *родился китенок, ежонок* и т.д.

Овцы, как правильно уже заметили, [ягнятся](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/918810) и почему-то еще и [котятся](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/901174).

Comment: у овец как ни странно - окот

Comment: "не значит, что есть фиолетоветь" а я считаю, что оно есть. Просто слово неудобное, потому редко встречается. В русском языке слова - собираются из блоков ,как конструктор. Поэтому не всегда вообще имеет смысл утверждение, что какое-то слово существует или нет. Это сродни вопросу, существует ли в русском языке фраза "он станет фиолетовым в крапинку". Есть ли такой словарь - именно словарь, в котором эта фраза наличествует?

Comment: Arioch,  у овец не окот. Вот у жирафов и бегемотов детёныши считаются телятами, потому как ни странно они телятся :) Но это не достоверная информация.

Comment: @Arioch, по такой логике есть слова "омедведиться" и "оёжиться". В каком-то смысле они есть, вернее могут быть построены по существующим в языке моделям. Это слова-[окказионализмы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)): за ними нет истории широкого употребления, они не входят в языковую норму, в отличие от *отелиться* и *окотиться*.

Comment: @gormih У овец вполне-таки окот.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: И оягн :)

Comment: Спасибо за термин. Ну да, развитие естественных языков, а отличие от синтетических, не укладывается в чёткие рамки и всегда в большей или меньшей степени дело вкуса и авторитета